# Get row count from second table in Propel ORM

Tags: php, symfony, propel

I'm somewhat new to Propel ORM, and the version I'm using is somewhat old (1.x). The app I'm working on cannot by any means be updated. I have the following schema:

```
<table name="blog">
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
    <column name="title" type="varchar" size="100" required="true" />
    <column name="user_id" type="integer" required="false" />
    <column name="author" type="varchar" size="100" required="true" default="Anonimous" />
    <column name="body" type="longvarchar" required="true" />
    <column name="publish_date" type="timestamp" required="true" />
    <behavior name="timestampable" />
    <behavior name="soft_delete" />
    <behavior name="sluggable">
        <parameter name="slug_pattern" value="{Title}" />
        <parameter name="replace_pattern" value="/[^\w]+/u" />
        <parameter name="replacement" value="-" />
        <parameter name="separator" value="-" />
        <parameter name="permanent" value="true" />
    </behavior>

    <foreign-key foreignTable="user">
        <reference local="user_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>

</table>

<table name="comment">
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
    <column name="blog_id" type="integer" required="true" />
    <column name="user_id" type="integer" required="false" default="-1" />
    <column name="author" type="varchar" required="false" default="Anonimous" />
    <column name="body" type="longvarchar" required="true" />

    <foreign-key foreignTable="user">
        <reference local="user_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>

    <foreign-key foreignTable="blog">
        <reference local="blog_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>

    <behavior name="timestampable" />
    <behavior name="soft_delete" />
</table>
```

I need to get by querying the blog table, the comment count for "each" blog entry.

here is my controller query:

```
$posts = BlogQuery::create()
        ->orderByPublishDate('desc')
        ->filterBy('PublishDate', time(), "<")
        ->paginate($page, $maxPerPage);
```

I need to add to each record, a count of the comments that belong to that particular record based on the blog_id as stated on the schema

```
<foreign-key foreignTable="blog">
    <reference local="blog_id" foreign="id"/>
</foreign-key>
```

Any one can give me a hand?

Comment: Propel 2.0 is in alpha, and development has slowed down a great deal. I don't think anyone should migrate yet, though I notice the Propel website seems to recommend the later version (both in terms of default docs and default download). I am still on 1.7.x, quite happy with it.

Comment: A simple solution is just to use `$posts[0]->countComments()`, which will issue a separate `COUNT(*)` query for the appropriate `Blog` row's related records.

Comment: thanl yuo @halfer the ->countComments did the trick, on the twig.

    Comments: {{post.countComments()}}

prints the comments for each blog post.

Comment: OK great, please post that as answer, which can be self-accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from a comments conversation:

> A simple solution is just to use `$posts[0]->countComments()`, which will issue a separate COUNT(*) query for the appropriate Blog row's related records.

The `->countComments()` did the trick, using Twig. This prints the comments for each blog post:

```
Comments: {{post.countComments()}}
```

Comment: And in the same way you can fetch each comment by just issuing the `getComments()`. I have a little note here, as i'm not sure the soft delete behavior will account for "deleted" comments you can just create an extra method in the model `blog`: `public function getOnlineComments() { return $this->getComments(CommentQuery::create()->filterByDeleted(false)); }`

Comment: Regarding my question, now, querying comments, is there a way to get, from comments, blog title ?

Comment: Propel uses two-way relationship. So its possible to do `$comment->getBlog()->getTitle()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code

```
BlogQuery::create('blog')
    ->leftJoinComment('comment')
    ->withColumn('COUNT(comment.id)', 'CommentCount')
    ->groupById()
    ->paginate($page, $maxPerPage);
```

Now you can use $blog->getCommentCount()